# Update list while adding the new item in a list of string in foreach loop

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a `List<string> assetIds = GetAllAssetId(assetentities);` called assetIds. Now suppose we have a list with 10 AssetIds in it. If you wanted to add the new AssetItems in a list of string and I need to update the list while doing the foreach loop. what would be the best way to do it?

Please have a look of the code here.
I am getting an `Error :Collection was modified;` enumeration operation may not execute. If I try to go for second time in foreach loop.

[image: e]

Comment: Post your code. We aren't going to type it in.

Comment: You cannot modify collection while iterating over it.

Comment: Post the *code*, not an image of the code. Don't ask for people to type your code just so they can test it

Comment: As for the question itself, you aren't just asking how to modify a list why iterating (you can't), you are *accessing the database* and calling `SaveChanges` for each item. *Don't* do that, it's extremely expensive. Modify all and call `SaveChanges` only once *outside* the loop. This will save all changes at once

Comment: Please find the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Yout change the collection in foreach loop so what you could do - make a copy of the collection in loop

```
foreach(var element in assetIds.ToList()) { 
    assetIds.Add(new Item());
)
```

**collection that the foreach loop operates on is different that the one you add to**
This is one way to get rid of the error. In your case I assume that there won't be any cases where the newly added item would be used twice.

Edit:
But again think if this is the solution that you want to go for. Maybe rewriting your code is better option

Comment: after making a collection in a loop how can i update the items in a foreach loop. I am looking for Suppose If i have a list of string and i want to stop adding the duplicate string in a list and if there is no duplicate, it should be added in a list and also update the original list while doing the foreach statement.

Comment: you call .AddToAssets  and .SaveChanges after the loop and it works fine